# ¿como puedo obtener los datos de un campo especifico de una tabl, mediante el uso de php y js?

Tags: php, javascript, tablas

Me surge un problema cuando trato de obtener el `id` de una tabla aquí

```
    $salida.="<table class='table'>
            <thead>
                <tr id='titulo'>
                    <th scope='col'>#Contrato</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Nombre</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Fecha Contrato</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Direccion</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Colonia</th>
                    <th scope='col'>Tipo de Cuota</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id='mytable'>";

    while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        $salida.="<tr style='cursor:pointer' onclick='al();'>    
                    <td class="id">".$fila['NUMECONTRA']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['NOMBREUSER']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['FECHACONTR']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['DIRECCUSER']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['COLONIAUSE']."</td>
                    <td>".$fila['TIPOCUOTAS']."</td>
                </tr>";

    }
    $salida.="</tbody>
                </table>";
}else{
    $salida.="NO HAY DATOS :(";
}


echo $salida;
```

y quiero poder obtener los datos del id mediante js el cual les dejo a continuación.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tr').click(function() {
    alert($(this).find('td.id').text())
  });
```

hice una prueba en un hoja de `HTML` y me agarra sin problemas.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr >
            <td class="id">45</td>
            <td>Bruce</td>
            <td>Almighty</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="id">22</td>
            <td>Bruce</td>
            <td>Evans</td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

La cuestión es que en la hoja de `PHP` no me agarra y no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: Tienes un error de sintaxis en `PHP`, cuando haces `<td class="id">".$fila['NUMECONTRA']."</td>`, deberías usar comillas simples, es decir, `<td class='id'>".`. En `JS` también tienes un error, te esta faltando cerrar con otro `});`

Comment: Probé tu código y funciona perfecto, lo que se me ocurre que el evento click sobre el tr esta siendo ejecutado cuando el documento este listo y la tabla existe después, trata de colocar ese evento click después de armar la tabla o cada vez que armes la tabla, asi el tr existirá antes de declarar el evento click y puedes atarlo como tal. Es cuestion de cuando declarar el evento click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no se repite tu identificador "id" pudiera cambiar el código:

```
<td class="id">".$fila['NUMECONTRA']."</td>
```

por:

```
<td class="fila" id="[el id que le estas pasando]">".$fila['NUMECONTRA']."</td>
```

y en el javascript:

`alert($(this).find('.fila').attr('id')) });`

Comment: muchas gracias, tu respuesta fue la que me ayudo :)

Comment: Me alegro, pudieras elegirla como la respuesta que te ayudo? Me ayudaría mucho =)

Comment: es en la palomita?, disculpa soy noob

Answer (score 0):

Si no puedes recuperar el valor via PHP javascript es otra solución:

```js
let ids = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".id"))

ids.forEach((id) =>{console.log(id.textContent)})
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr >
            <td class="id">45</td>
            <td>Bruce</td>
            <td>Almighty</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="id">22</td>
            <td>Bruce</td>
            <td>Evans</td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```